# Case insensitive list item comparison python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working trough the Python Crash Course book and I am doing this assignment.

> Do the following to create a program that simulates how websites ensure that everyone has a unique username.
>
> - Make a list of five or more usernames called `current_users`.
> - Make another list of five usernames called `new_users`. Make sure one or two of the new usernames are also in the `current_users` list.
> - Loop through the `new_users` list to see if each new username has already been used. If it has, print a message that the person will need to enter a new username. If a username has not been used, print a message saying that the username is available.
> - Make sure your comparison is case insensitive. If `'John'` has been used, `'JOHN'` should not be accepted.

I can see if a username in one list is in another with.

```
current_users = ["John", "Admin", "Jack", "Ana", "Natalie"]
new_users = ["Pablo", "Donald", "Calvin", "Natalie", "Emma"]

for username in new_users:
    if username in current_users:
        print("Username unavailable.")
    else:
        print("Username available.")
```

Now for the case insensitive part I know about the .lower() method, but not sure how to convert a list item to lowercase in the loop. I could do `if username.lower() in current_users`, which wouldn't work because I need to covert current_users somehow. Is there a better way then just doing `.lower()` for both lists before the loop.

Comment: no, unless one list is already lowercase

Comment: If the names in `new_users` are always title-cased, you can call `.title()` on `current_users`.

Comment: @mpf82 that works thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should convert your `current_users` into a lowercase set and then do blazignly fast comparisons for each of your new users, just lowercased, e.g.:

```
current_users = ["John", "Admin", "Jack", "Ana", "Natalie"]
new_users = ["Pablo", "Donald", "Calvin", "Natalie", "Emma"]

current_users_lookup = {user.lower() for user in current_users}
for user in new_users:
    if user.lower() in current_users_lookup:
        print("Username {} unavailable.".format(user))
    else:
        print("Username {} available.".format(user))
```

Which would get you:

```
Username Pablo available.
Username Donald available.
Username Calvin available.
Username Natalie unavailable.
Username Emma available.
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert everything to lowercase before doing your test:

```
current_users = ["John", "Admin", "Jack", "Ana", "Natalie"]
new_users = ["Pablo", "Donald", "Calvin", "Natalie", "Emma"]

current_users = [x.lower() for x in current_users] 
new_users = [x.lower() for x in new_users]
```

If you're new to Python this is called [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
for username in new_users:
    if username in current_users:
        print("Username unavailable.")
    else:
        print("Username available.")
```

Or if the first letter of the usernames is always capitalized, you can use .title()

```
for username in new_users:
    if username.title() in current_users:
        print("Username unavailable.")
    else:
        print("Username available.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an new list with lowerCase characters and then to check with it.

```
current_users = ["John", "Admin", "Jack", "Ana", "Natalie"]
new_users = ["Pablo", "Donald", "Calvin", "Natalie", "Emma"]  

current_users_lower = map(str.lower,current_users)
for username in new_users:
  if username.lower() in current_users_lower:
    print("Username unavailable.")
  else:
    print("Username available.")
```